# reducing memory footprint of phonegap, sencha touch on iOS (iPad)

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha Touch 1.1 along with PhoneGap to deploy code on the iPad. In Instruments the memory usage shows up at around 140MB (virtual memory) and then does go up at some places to higher than 200 MB and my app gets killed at times due to large lists which I am fixing to reduce the DOM footprint. I tried testing out the sencha touch app from Safari and the memory did not grow to these limits, Safari on start was around 160MB and it went up to 200+ MB, but most times stayed in the 170-180MB range.

My next test was to figure out the impact of PhoneGap framework. The sample Hello world application when I install phonegap and try it out already seems to be using around 100 MB (virtual memory). I tried to search on the web to determine how this footprint can be reduced but did not find anything.

My question is the following - what can I do to reduce the phonegap footprint and is it even relevant to helping reduce crashes of my application? I see other applications like Flipboard which are native using a lot less memory (60-70 MB) and was trying to understand why the basic footprint of a phonegap app is 100+ MB while this phonegap + sencha-touch based app is hovering in the 150 - 200 MB range.

Anand

Answer (score 1):

You should look at removing the number of plugins your PhoneGap app loads. That is either controlled by an xml file (Android, BB) or by a plist (iOS). For instance if you are not using Contacts then don't load that Plugin, etc.

Comment: Had already removed most things in the XML file already in PG plist. This still did not help as the memory post all this was at 100 MB. The test is pretty simple, just start a default PG project in XCode, remove stuff from plist and run and instrument. If this is normal or expected behavior, its OK, but was expecting PG to use a lot less.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your app in Safari was around 160MB so I think that's not (at least) just phonegap. So try to improve your sencha touch app. Probably you don't destroy containers you don't use or something similar. Check this video for details: https://vimeo.com/17882927

Comment: Yes, I have been fixing a lot of things on the Sencha touch side, but what I see is by the time I get to login of my app, which means sencha touch loaded and my app code loaded, and minimal DOM with just a login screen, it is already at 135-140 MB. The bigger contribution is phone gap and its infrastructure of this at 100 MB so was looking to see if this could be reduced.

Comment: I have done things like destroying items that are not needed, using common event handlers, and the memory has improved, also moving to use UxBufferedList which helps in reducing memory, but still has some nasty side effects that need fixing in the UI. So now memory is more controlled but still very high.

Comment: You can also try to minify your JS files. Also have you tried the new Sencha Touch native wrapper?

Comment: Minifying and building js files have already been done using the sencha build jsb3 file and the css are in production mode. So all the easy stuff has already been done and am looking for what else I can do, more on the phonegap side for the startup. I am also trying out Sencha Touch 2.0 B2 with native packaging to see if that helps in reducing the footprint.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this. I often develop apps with phonegap and had concerns about the memory consumption but never had the time to inspect it my self. Please get back with the results of the ST2 native packaging.

Comment: Will definitely get back on this, what I have been surprised about is the lack of information on this topic, one does find general guidelines, help, etc but nothing substancial in terms of numbers and data to help to confirm if one is on the right track, or what you get whether it is normal expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring closure, moved to Sencha 2.0 and using PhoneGap 2.0 the memory usage is still in the range of 150 ~ 200 MB but now with all the usage on the app I do not see crashes. I have seen apps like Flipboard consume 350 MB and still work so now this is not an issue.

The basic Safari mobile browser occupied memory in the range of 100 ~150+ and so I cannot expect the usage to come down a lot more.